# how to match paper sheet by opencv

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, opencv, matching

I have some kinds of paper sheet and I am writing python script with opencv to recognize the same paper sheet to classify. I am stuck in how to find the same kind of paper sheet. For example, I attached two pic. Picture 1 is the template and picture 2 is some kind of paper I need to know if it is matching with the template. I don't need to match the text and I just need to match the form. I need to classify the same sheet in many of paper sheet.

I have adjust the skew of paper and detect some lines but I don't know how to match the lines and judge this paper sheet is the same kind with the template.

Is there any one can give me an advice for the matching algorithm?[image: This is the paper sheet template][image: This is the paper sheet I need to match with the template][image: Need matching the lines]

Comment: Is there anyone could share some thought with me about this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if such paper form is rich enough in visual information for this solution, but I think you should start with feature detection and homography calculation (opencv tutorial: [Features2D + Homography](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html#feature-homography)). From there you can try to adjust 2D features for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the findContours and MatchShape function. Either way, you are much better off matching a specific visual ID within the form that is representative of the form. Like a really simple form of barcode.